# rename dataframe column wierd special char showing

Tags: python, dataframe, rename

df_Tet.rename(columns={"field.customfield_114":"Test Memo Title"})

I get column name to be

[image]

Comment: What's between "Test" and "Memo" is not a space. Delete what's in between then type a space using your keyboard.

Comment: Apparently, you have a "NO-BREAK SPACE" instead of a keyboard space.

Answer (score 0):

Inplace should be True

```
df_Tet.rename(columns = {'"field.customfield_114':'Test Memo Title'}, inplace = True)
```